# Запись диска восстановления на флешку

Tags: восстановление, диск

Если я это сделаю, смогу ли я воспользоваться этой флешкой в том объёме , в котором я бы этим воспользовался, если бы вместо флешки использовал оптический диск? Ведь изначально для этого предполагалось использовать именно оптические диски.

Comment: изначально - это когда не было флешек? У меня, например, была дискета  для восстановления ещё до появления у меня CD-ROM'a

Comment: Да, до этого  самого.

Comment: Кстати , вы не путаете диск восстановления с образом системы ?

Comment: не, не путаю, я так DOS (кажется, версии 6.22) как то восстанавливал

Comment: У вас уже тогда был комп?! Фантастика ! Они же тогда были такие дорогие ! Помню , в 88-ом году у нас в подъезде комп был только в одной семье - в семье кооперативщика.

Comment: не, у многиз тогда уже была винда 3.11. Мне просто подарили списанный старый компьютер, это было где то в году 96-97. Диски тогда в нашей глуши были диковинкой (а может их и вообще не было, я уже не помню), мы все переписывали дискетами.